# My PCRE Regex Pattern for detecting a String with Many Words is not Working

Tags: php, regex, string

I would love to detect the following strings only:

```
pets ok
pets yes
pets allowed
pets accepted
pets is/are allowed
pets is/are accepted
pets will be considered
pets will considered
pets is/are considered
pet friendly
```

and the same thing with the reverse like:

```
ok pets
yes pets
...
```

*(same as above, just with "pets"/"pet" from beginning at the end)*

I can not figure this out.

Please, if you can help me improve my current pattern which is obviously not working:

```
/\\b(pet(?:s)?\\s[negotiable|ok|o\\.k|friendly|accept|allow|possible]+|[ok|yes|accept]+\\spet(?:s)?|pet(?:s)?\\s[will|will\\sbe]+\\s[consider|allow|accept|possible]+)\\b/i"
```

Comment: Reduce your requirements. Just start with the first two lines and get them to work for both directions. You will then quickly be able to finish this.

Comment: You say you want to match those strings only, but you have `negotiable` in your regex.

Comment: I forgot to include it sorry.

Comment: The problem is that it is nor *clear* from your question what you *exactly*  need to match. Your question is ambiguous. Improve it to get better answers. Also as I already suggested, reduce your requirements first which will allow you to better solve this your own. And provide an actual code-example so that your question is more concise. Also: *"not working"* is not a question.

Comment: You can use an interactive tool to very quickly debug regex's. Like http://rubular.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a super-strict regex which will only match the examples you listed (and didn't finish listing):

```
\b(?:(?:pets (?:ok|yes|(?:(?:is\/are )?(?:allowed|accepted))|(?:(?:will(?: be)?|is\/are) considered)))|(?:(?:ok|yes|(?:(?:is\/are )?(?:allowed|accepted))|(?:(?:will(?: be)?|is\/are) considered))) pets|pet friendly|friendly pet)\b​
```

## [See it on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/wNxkXpOX1W)

I basically split it up into the variations of "allowed/accepted" and the variations of "considered". Then I just copied it for the opposite way.

The most human readable form would still be:

```
\b(?:pets ok|pets yes|pets allowed|pets accepted|pets is\/are allowed|pets is\/are accepted|pets will be considered|pets will considered|pets is\/are considered|pet friendly|ok pets|yes pets|allowed pets|is\/are allowed pets|accepted pets|is\/are accepted pets|will be considered pets|will considered pets|is\/are considered pets|friendly pet)\b
```

Also, in your regex, you seem to be using character classes (`[ ]`) for seperating words, when you should in fact be using non-capture groups (`(?: )`)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
"/\\bpets?\\s[ok|is\\/are allowed]/i"
```

and silimar